# SSIS workflow design confusion

Tags: ssis

Question from an SSIS noob. I come from a C# background and noticed a lot can be achieved using Script Task component in SSIS.

The task that I have to achieve is as follows: Get a list of a students's roll numbers from (sql table), say 1,23,4 and 56. There is marksheet folder containing M1.pdf, M2.pdf,..M65.pdf etc(naming convention is M followed by roll number.pdf) for all the students in the class. So for above list of students, i.e. 1, 23, 4 and 56, grab pdfs M1.pdf, M23.pdf, M4.pdf, M56.pdf, zip these four pdfs and email to the dean.

Could an SSIS expert please suggest if all of this can be achieved without script task. I understand that getting SQL resultset, zipping and emailing is easy. But can the logic of getting the list of pdfs (M1.pdf, M23.pdf...) is possible using any SSIS component other than Script Task? Can Foreach be used here?

Comment: Query generates a result. Those results will tie to files on the file system. All the files need to get passed into a zip command and the resultant archive is then sent via email. That about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the Foreach Loop Container.

First, built a Data Flow Task to deliver the results of your SQL query into a Variable (type Object) using a Recordset Destination.

Then add the Foreach Loop Container to your Control Flow. On the Collection pane, set Enumerator to: Foreach ADO Enumerator and select your Variable. On the Variable Mappings pane create New Variables for each column you need (from your SQL Query).  Note the Index is positional, driven by the config of your Recordset Destination.

Now the Foreach Loop Container will fire once for each row in your Recordset, and you can use the new Variables to access the values from each row.